# Unresolved reference error in PyCharm

Tags: python

I am pretty new to python, so I decided to make a basic calculator application using functions, however, whenever I try to invoke one of my calculation functions, it says it is an Unresolved reference to the function. I have looked around, but I am not sure what is happening.

My code:

```
class BasicCalculator:
    # define functions
    def add(x, y):
        """This function adds two numbers"""
        return x + y

    def subtract(x, y):
        """This function subtracts two numbers"""
        return x - y

    def multiply(x, y):
        """This function multiplies two numbers"""
        return x * y

    def divide(x, y):
        """This function divides two numbers"""
        return x / y

    def power(x, y):
        """This function does a power of two numbers"""
        return x ** y


if __name__ == '__main__':

    print("Select an operator")
    print("1. Add")
    print("2. Subtract")
    print("3. Multiply")
    print("4. Divide")
    print("5. Power")

    left = int(input("Enter your left number: "))
    choice = int(input("Select your operator(1, 2, 3, 4): "))
    right = int(input("Select your right number: "))

    if choice == '1':
        #Error is here, it says "Unresolved reference 'add'"
        print(add(left, right))
    else:
        print("Invalid input")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has 4 issues that you need to fix:

**1st:** You need to add `self` as the first argument to all your methods inside `BasicCalculator` class, `self` is a reference to the current instance of the class:

```
class BasicCalculator:
    # define functions
    def add(self, x, y):  # self must be the first argument
        """This function adds two numbers"""
        return x + y

    # ...
```

**2nd:** You need to instantiate your class:

```
calculator = BasicCalculator()
```

**3rd:** Call your functions like this:

```
calculator.add(left, right)
```

**4th:** You need to fix your `if` statement:

```
if choice == 1:  # not '1', because choice is an integer (choice = int(input("...")))
```

**All together:** Your code should now be as follows:

```
class BasicCalculator:
    # define functions
    def add(self, x, y):
        """This function adds two numbers"""
        return x + y

    def subtract(self, x, y):
        """This function subtracts two numbers"""
        return x - y

    def multiply(self, x, y):
        """This function multiplies two numbers"""
        return x * y

    def divide(self, x, y):
        """This function divides two numbers"""
        return x / y

    def power(self, x, y):
        """This function does a power of two numbers"""
        return x ** y


if __name__ == '__main__':

    print("Select an operator")
    print("1. Add")
    print("2. Subtract")
    print("3. Multiply")
    print("4. Divide")
    print("5. Power")

    left = int(input("Enter your left number: "))
    choice = int(input("Select your operator(1, 2, 3, 4): "))
    right = int(input("Select your right number: "))

    calculator = BasicCalculator()

    if choice == 1:
        print(calculator.add(left, right))
    else:
        print("Invalid input")
```

Comment: What does "self" do in this context? Also what does "calculator = BasicCalculator()" do?

Comment: `self` is a reference to the current instance of the class. `calculator = BasicCalculator()` means that we instantiate this class (`BasicCalculator`), in other words, we create an object of type `BasicCalculator`

Answer (score 0):

The function `add` is defined within the class `BasicCalculator`. You need to do `BasicCalculator.add()`. You could also just define `add` outside of the class.

Basically, just change this line `print(add(left, right))` to `print(BasicCalculator.add(left, right))`

Also, its worth doing a check if the other two variables (left and right) are properly initialized. So change `if choice == '1':` to `if (choice == '1') and (left is not None) and (right is not None):`

Answer (score 0):

Your functions are defined inside a class I believe - although the indentation you wrote here is not entirely consistent. You could try:
 -

- either remove the first line "class BasicCalculator:"
- call your functions in the right namespace: BasicCalculator.add(left,right)

Comment: If you choose the former, you will need to rethink your indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Make an instance of your calculator

```
choice = input("Select your operator(1, 2, 3, 4): ") # Not an int
calc = BasicCalculator()
if choice == '1':  # You are comparing strings, not ints
    print(calc.add(left, right))
```